# How can I retrieve results with grouped where in query

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve results from my `posts` table with the following query. I want to select posts, where both conditions in the where part of the statement are passes.

**WHERE the term type is category and is in CategoryTest**

**AND WHERE the term type is tag and is in TagTest**

`WHERE IN` conditions are currently contains one element, but could be more. *Both* `WHERE` gives the result if the other is not presented. **So each one works alone or with the `OR` also works.** It gaves back the same post, with the id 33 - so I think the WHERE group not set properly.

```
SELECT `posts`.*
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `post_term` ON `posts`.`id` = `post_term`.`post_id`
LEFT JOIN `terms` ON `terms`.`id`= `post_term`.`term_id`
LEFT JOIN `meta` ON `meta`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id`
WHERE   (
    `terms`.`type` = 'category'
    AND `terms`.`name` IN('CategoryTest')
 )
AND   (
        `terms`.`type` = 'tag'
        AND `terms`.`name` IN('TagTest')
 )
```

Table definitions:
**Terms table**

`+----+--------------+--------------+----------+
| id | name         | slug         | type     |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------+
| 31 | CategoryTest | CategoryTest | category |
| 32 | TagTest      | TagTest      | tag      |
+----+--------------+--------------+----------+`

**Posts table:**

`+----+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| id | title | content | user_id | parent_id | created_at | updated_at |
+----+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 33 | HEllo |         |       0 |         0 | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+-------+---------+---------+-----------+------------+------------+`

**post_term**

`+----+---------+---------+
| id | post_id | term_id |
+----+---------+---------+
| 73 |      33 |      31 |
| 74 |      33 |      32 |
+----+---------+---------+`

Comment: You say "OR" works. Then why not to use it?

Comment: Can you show the terms table definition?OR better yet some sample data

Comment: I want to retrieve results, where both conditions passes, not only one of them.

Comment: You seem to not know really what you need. `terms`.`type` can not be 'category' and 'tag' at the same time

Comment: I want to get posts, which have TagTest tag, and CategoryTest category. Probably it's a wrong direction. Thats why I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check with `exists`:

```
select * from posts p
where 
  exists(select * from post_term pt join Terms t on pt.term_id = t.id 
         where pt.post_id = p.id and t.name = 'category') and
  exists(select * from post_term pt join Terms t on pt.term_id = t.id 
         where pt.post_id = p.id and t.name = 'tag')
```

Comment: Welcome, I just didn't get what was desired before your last comment.

Comment: For multiple `name` check is just: `...and t.name IN('tag1', 'tag2')` right?

Comment: Yes, but it will give you the result if ANY exists. If you need to check if ALL of names are present you will also need to separate it into different `exists` parts

Comment: Got it! Yes, in the `where in` it's enough to exists at least one.